# Method will be called more than twice from one thread. How to wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

A C#-method is calling on the main-thread after event raising. Then an another event is firing this same method during the first event is busy with the same method. So during debugging, I see in the calling stack two line in the same method on the same thread.

How can I hinder that the second event waits until the first event is ready with the same method. I'm trying with lock() but it doesn't block the same thread. AutoResetEvent can wait but will be waiting on the same thread.

Somebody has the tip? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Application.DoEvents?  Post some code.

Comment: ShowDialog would be another way to shoot the foot.

Comment: @Henk Holterman. Application.DoEvents(), of course. After analyse the call stack again (lot of lines) I see during the first firing of the event an call to Application.DoEvents(). So this trigger to fire the events that are in que. Thanks (please feel free to enter your advice as answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `Application.DoEvents()`. This method does have its uses but it is dangerous, you stumbled onto one of the reasons : re-entrant calls to events.

So, try

1. remove and avoid DoEvents().
2. or make **all** your eventhandlers capable of or resistant to re-entrancy. Take a critical look at what scenarios are possible with the close button for instance. A simple trick could be:

```
private bool busy = false;    
private void MyHandler(sender s, EventArgs e)
{
  if (busy)
    return;   // giving up, no queuing

  busy = true;
  // code
  busy = false;  // maybe in a finally clause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the method with [*MethodImplAttribute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) attribute.

### Example:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
void Method()
{
   ....
}
```

### Documentation ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx)):

*MethodImplOptions.Synchronized*

Specifies that the method can be executed by only one thread at a time. Static methods lock on the type, whereas instance methods lock on the instance. Only one thread can execute in any of the instance functions, and only one thread can execute in any of a class's static functions.

Comment: And not much different than `lock`

Comment: Ah, you are right, Henk. In that case, a Queue type mechanism should be used to post any new calls to that method on that Queue. All the items on the Queue should be processed one by one. Of course, this requires another (processor) thread.

Comment: Decyclone: MethodImpl is not the solution because it's still one thread :) (said by Henk Holterman). Queue is also not the solution because the even will running in a seperated thread. Thanks.